# jquery work on click event but not while it is clicked and dragged

Tags: jquery

I wrote an click event to be executed on a grid.
the event is

```
$("#gridId").click(function(){
   var data = .....;
   $.ajax( {
    ......
   });
});
```

It works fine if i click on a particular grid Say the 5th grid.
But when i click and drag to select some 5 grid. Say from 5 - 10th grid. It is not working.
I'm not sure where do i go wrong. 
 Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML (and, possibly, the CSS) for the elements it's going to be difficult to help you. That said, there's nothing in the code you've posted that looks like it even remotely deals with moving the mouse between pressing and releasing the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the same ID for all the grids - which is the problem.

You must have unique ID then have the same **class** for all of them - e.g. if you give them all `class="mygrid" then just change the code to:

```
$(".mygrid").click(function(){
    //......
});
```

This will handle the `click` event for all elements having this class.

Comment: Can I use the same class name for CSS changes and for this click event or do I need to change the CSS which i used for CSS as ID?

Comment: @saran sorry not sure what you mean. If you mean you already have CSS class then yes, you can use it instead. I brought "mygrid" just as example.

Comment: I have a css class named "timeevent", i tried as you said --- $(".timeevent").click(function()... but it didn't work.

Comment: @saran should work. If you put `alert('clicked');` in the function do you see it? If so, please edit your post and put more code so we can find what is the real problem here.